# Macbook pro iOS/Android dev setup with Xamarin

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin

I've been doing iOS dev work for a year or two now, along with some Xamarin work on Windows and I'm looking for an ultimate dev configuration that allows me to get rid of my two machines and just use a Macbook with Parallels.  However, I have a few questions that are still unanswered:

1) Use a real keyboard/mouse (I find working on Mac keyboard/mouse not quite as productive)
2) Have a Thunderbolt Ethernet connection (our wifi is not always the best)
3) Have an output to two additional monitors, which could show both Windows OS, both Mac OS, or one of each.

Is this too much to ask?  Anyone else have this configuration?  If so is there anything I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

James

Comment: I use a windows mouse and keyboard and it works just fine. I also output my parallels window to a second monitor and use my Macbook monitor to show my mac screen. I have not gone out a bought a thunderbolt connector to get ethernet working but I have wanted to, just think it is ridiculous that I have to purchase something else just to have ethernet on a Macbook Pro (emphasis on the word PRO and the lack of PRO sockets)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that is probably better suited to the [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/).  However, the set up you describe is one of the arrangements I use myself.  The only difference is that I use a Mac keyboard.  You should be able to use a PC keyboard perfectly fine but you may choose to remap some keys in the Mac preferences.

The only thing I can think of to be aware of is that while you can use nested virtualisation to run an emulator inside the Windows VM it will be significantly slower than running it on your Mac natively.  As such, if you intend to code for Android, I would suggest running the AVDs on your Mac and [connecting to them remotely from Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows/).